# Slide div from right to left but only one div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I am adding another div and it is not working. If I add another it should work:

HTML

```
<div id="siteMap">
  <div id="mapButton">button</div>
  <div id="theMap">content here</div>
</div>
<div id="siteMap" style="margin-top:90px;">
  <div id="mapButton">button</div>
  <div id="theMap">content here</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#siteMap {
  width:200px;
  position:fixed;
  right:-200px;
  top:0px;
  display:block;
  color:#FFF;
  z-index:2;
  opacity: 0.95;
}
#siteMap #mapButton {
  display:block;
  color:#333;
  background-color:#ACACAC;
  padding:2px 5px;
  height:20px;
  width:70px;
  text-align:center;
  position:relative;
  right: 24px;
  margin-top:80px;
  cursor:pointer;
  transform-origin: 0% 0%;
  -ms-transform-origin: 0% 0%;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 0% 0%;
  -moz-transform-origin: 0% 0%;
  -o-transform-origin: 0% 0%;
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg); 
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg); 
  -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg); 
  -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
}
#siteMap #theMap {
  width:100%;
  height:100px;
  background-color:#666;
  margin-top:-104px;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#mapButton').click(function() {
    var mapPos = parseInt($('#siteMap').css('right'), 10);
    if (mapPos < 0) {
      $('#siteMap').animate({
        right: '+=200'
        }, 458, 'swing', function() {
          // Animation complete.
      });
    } else {
      $('#siteMap').animate({
        right: '-=200'
        }, 458, 'swing', function() {
          // Animation complete.
      });
    }
  });
});
```

How to work this out? I need it to animate those divs even when adding another div.

Here is [the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qGVfp/27/).

Comment: First of all you defined same id 2 times , but id must be unique. you can not define same id twice.

Comment: you can try this tutorial for better result

http://www.themeswild.com/read/slide-navigation-left-to-right

Answer (score 2):

When you use `$('#mapButton')` it finds the first element with such id. Id should be uniq. Use classes instead of ids.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.mapButton').click(function () {
    var siteMap = $(this).parent();

    var mapPos = parseInt(siteMap.css('right'), 10);
    if (mapPos < 0) {
      siteMap.animate({
        right: '+=200'
      }, 458, 'swing', function () {
        // Animation complete.
      });
    } else {
      siteMap.animate({
        right: '-=200'
      }, 458, 'swing', function () {
        // Animation complete.
      });
    }
  });
});
```

Working Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/xttaw/

Answer (score 2):

Id must be unique, you should use classes instead:

```
$('.mapButton').click(function() {
  var mapPos = parseInt($(this).parent().css('right'), 10);
  if (mapPos < 0) {
    $(this).parent().animate({
      right: '+=200'
      }, 458, 'swing', function() {
        // Animation complete.
      });
  }
  else {
    $(this).parent().animate({
      right: '-=200'
      }, 458, 'swing', function() {
        // Animation complete.
    });
  } 
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qGVfp/29/

Comment: Hi there, is there any way that when i click outside the button it closes all the contents.

Answer (score 1):

Use class instead of ids, i.e., use `class="siteMap"`(`.siteMap` in CSS) instead of `id="siteMap"`. And also make use of `$(this).parent()` to access parent element. Check the updated code here: http://jsfiddle.net/qGVfp/28/

Answer (score 1):

In this code

```
<div id="siteMap">
 <div id="mapButton">button</div>
 <div id="theMap">content here</div>
</div>
<div id="siteMap" style="margin-top:90px;">
 <div id="mapButton">button</div>
 <div id="theMap">content here</div>
</div>
```

You are having same id twice like `<div id="mapButton">` and  `<div id="siteMap">`

Which is not recommended same id's multiple times in HTMl .

Try to use `css class` to write `javascript`

Comment: comment when down vote a post. it's good thing to give feedback

Answer (score 0):

id values must be unique per document, so you cannot have multiple <div id="siteMap"> or anything else.

Consider using classes instead. That is, <div class="siteMap"... and so on. Update your css and jquery selectors accordingly ('.siteMap')

EDIT: Try this (untested)

```
<div class="siteMap">
  <div class="mapButton">button</div>
  <div class="theMap">content here</div>
</div>
<div class="siteMap" style="margin-top:90px;">
  <div class="mapButton">button</div>
  <div class="theMap">content here</div>
</div>



.siteMap {
  width:200px;
  position:fixed;
  right:-200px;
  top:0px;
  display:block;
  color:#FFF;
  z-index:2;
  opacity: 0.95;
}
.siteMap .mapButton {
  display:block;
  color:#333;
  background-color:#ACACAC;
  padding:2px 5px;
  height:20px;
  width:70px;
  text-align:center;
  position:relative;
  right: 24px;
  margin-top:80px;
  cursor:pointer;
  transform-origin: 0% 0%;
  -ms-transform-origin: 0% 0%;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 0% 0%;
  -moz-transform-origin: 0% 0%;
  -o-transform-origin: 0% 0%;
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg); 
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg); 
  -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg); 
  -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
}
.siteMap .theMap {
  width:100%;
  height:100px;
  background-color:#666;
  margin-top:-104px;
}





$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.mapButton').click(function() {
    var mapPos = parseInt($(this).parent().css('right'), 10);
    if (mapPos < 0) {
      $(this).parent().animate({
        right: '+=200'
        }, 458, 'swing', function() {
          // Animation complete.
      });
    } else {
      $(this).parent().animate({
        right: '-=200'
        }, 458, 'swing', function() {
          // Animation complete.
      });
    }
  });
});
```